# rsync copies identical files

Tags: rsync, fat32

I use rsync to copy my files to a external usb hdd:

```
rsync -av --max-size=4G --exclude "*.ini" --exclude "Thumbs.db" --delete /sourcefiles/ /destination/
```

This works so far, but when I run the command a second time, the same files are copied again. This should not be the case since the were copied a few moments ago.

Comment: Then something changed the file, a timestamp of the file would be sufficient to copy the file again.

Comment: If target is FAT: http://askubuntu.com/questions/112863/rsync-not-working-between-ntfs-fat-and-ext

Comment: timestamp of access and modify are the same but the change timestamp is different:
external: Change: 2016-10-16 11:42:16.000000000 +0200 (current date)
local: Change: 2012-03-06 19:25:24.272845200 +0100

I tried to use the parameter -t to copy the timestap but it didnt

BTW the external usb hdd uses fat32

Comment: If you don't get a satisfactory answer here, try asking the rsync folks directly. They are very helpful and the developers answer a lot of the questions too. You can join the list at https://lists.samba.org/mailman/listinfo/rsync . The first thing you should do is add a -i to your command which will give you a lot more information about what is happening.

Comment: The problem was a missing slash in the source path....